# Updating Mongo Object Field

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to update an object stored in Mongo that gets created as part of every new users document when they register for my site. By default this object is empty.

How can I push data directly into this object which is within the subfield profile.history.

So far I have been only able to push data into the root of the document itself.

Looking at the image, as stated, I want to write to the history object in profile.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about the Meteor.users collection, below is some code:

```
let myDynamicField = 'foo'; // Or whatever you want, an input value for example...
let update = {};
update[`profile.history.${myDynamicField1}`] = 'blah';

Meteor.users.update(
{
    "_id": "testing123"
}, 
{
    $set: {
        update
    }
});
```

*Edited to reflect what the user was asking for in the comments.

Comment: Yeah that would work but I want to write multiple fields to the saves object. (I shouldn't have explained before). I would like to create a new object within the history object.

Comment: Doesn't the same hold true?  I think you can just as easily do "profile.history.foo.bar" and it will create the appropriate missing objects.

Comment: I guess that works. Now I just need to figure out how to dynamically change that foo value.

Comment: See my revised answer.  I'm using this in a project of mine.

Comment: I tried using a code pattern like that and it didn't work. update in $set:{} was throwing an error. (Maybe I misunderstood your answer and you were implying something with the update).